# HorizontalPodAutoscaler multiple replica upscale

Tags: kubernetes

I am using a Horizontal Pod Autoscaler in Kubernetes as shown below. I want to use it for a service to scale between 4 and 40 replicas. Unfortunately due to the upscale delay it would take roughly an hour to scale from 4 to 40 replicas. Is there any chance I could provide something like a min/max Surge to upscale replicas? So that it would at least upscale by 2 or 4 replicas?

My API Object (helm):

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ required "A valid service.name entry required!" .Values.service.name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.service.name }}
    version: {{ .Values.image.tag | quote }}
    chart: {{ template "nodejs.chart" . }}
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ required "A valid service.name entry required!" .Values.service.name }}
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.autoscaling.minReplicas }}
  maxReplicas: {{ .Values.autoscaling.maxReplicas }}
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageValue: {{ required "A valid autoscaling.cpuTargetValue entry is required" .Values.autoscaling.cpuTargetValue }}
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      targetAverageValue: {{ required "A valid autoscaling.memoryTargetValue entry is required" .Values.autoscaling.memoryTargetValue }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. It seems that you are concerned about *thrashing*. There's not really a way to define an upscale *step* number combined with a cool off period.

Up until Kubernetes 1.11 you can specify the [`--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-upscale-delay`](https://v1-11.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-cooldown-delay) on the kube-controller-manager which defaults to 3 minutes. This may not be enough, so I created this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69428)

So starting with Kubernetes 1.12 that option has been removed in favor of a [better scaling algorithm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-cooldown-delay).

Comment: I am aware of the upscale-delay, however the delay makes sense and 3minutes should also be fine for me. However the more replicas you are running the less a single pod up/downscale affects the overall load. Does this in turn mean a HPA is not suited for deployments with many replicas? I'd be very disappointed then.

Comment: It should be able to handle thousands of new replicas, but there are other factors and vary case by case. For example, what application are you running? Is your application needing a lot CPU burst?  Anyways, that's why opened the ticket and looks like the put in some fixes in 1.12